# How to check database for object using equivalence by foreign object in laravel/eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have `User` and `Pet` models, and a `User` might have many `Pet`s, which then have `name`s, which are unique (in our bizarre world). Using Eloquent, how can I find a `User` using only their `Pet`'s name, since `Pet` isn't directly referenced by `User`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `User` model:

```
public function pets() {
  return $this->hasMany('Pet');
}
```

The reciprocal relationship (unnecessary for the scope of this question, but likely useful) in the `Pet` model:

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

In your `Pet` database table, you'd have a `user_id` column.

You can then access a user's pets with `$user->pets`, and a pet's user with `$pet->user`.

Comment: So, just look up the `Pet` and return its `User`?

Comment: Yes. `$user = Pet::where('name', 'Fluffy')->first()->user;` should do the trick.